# WIX Installer:: Install SQL EXPRESS/IIS Express depending on Radio button selection

Tags: wix

I have wix installer with radio buttons on ui screen.
I have to install SQL/IIS express depending on radio button selection in wix installer.
I am new to wix installer.
Can anyone please provide me some solution/references to proceed ahead?

Thanking you

Comment: You could use Visual Studio Installer projects to make a setup.exe that installs SQL for you - IIS Express might be a single file deployment or possible to install yourself - I am not sure. I don't think it should be re-distributed to be honest. Then you can deliver a WiX MSI to install your product. You can also wrap it all in a setup.exe made by WiX's Burn mechanism. Sorry, not time to add details. A search will find you more - I have several on Burn. Try my experimental site: installdude.com.

Comment: Please help me out the with some code sample or any reference as I am new to wix installer.